# BROADCASTJOIN hint is not working in PySpark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to provide broadcast hint to table which is smaller in size, but physical plan is still showing me SortMergeJoin.

`spark.sql('select /*+ BROADCAST(pratik_test_temp.crosswalk2016) */ * from pratik_test_staging.crosswalk2016 t join pratik_test_temp.crosswalk2016 c on t.serial_id = c.serial_id').explain()`

Output :
[image]

Note :

1. Size of tables are in KBs (test data)
2. Joining column 'serial_id' is not partitioned column
3. Using glue catalog as metastore (AWS)
4. Spark Version - Spark 2.4.4
5. I have tried BROADCASTJOIN and MAPJOIN hint as well
6. When I am trying to use `created_date` [partitioned column] instead of `serial_id` as my joining condition, it is showing me BroadCast Join -

`spark.sql('select /*+ BROADCAST(pratik_test_temp.crosswalk2016) */ * from pratik_test_staging.crosswalk2016 t join pratik_test_temp.crosswalk2016 c on t.created_date = c.created_date').explain()`

Output -
[image]

Why spark behavior is strange with AWS Glue Catalog as my metastore?

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **`BROADCAST`** hint we need to pass the **`alias name of the table`** (as you have alias kept in your sql statement).

Try with  **`/*+ BROADCAST(c) */*`** instead of `/*+ BROADCAST(pratik_test_temp.crosswalk2016) */ *`

---

```
spark.sql('select /*+ BROADCAST(c) */ * from pratik_test_staging.crosswalk2016 t join pratik_test_temp.crosswalk2016 c on t.serial_id = c.serial_id').explain()
```