# How to force enable broadcast join in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mapjoin

I have a spark SQL query that goes like this -

```
SELECT /*+ BROADCASTJOIN (sbg_published.sk_e2e_web_all_vis) */
       a.* 
FROM 
       sbg_published.sk_e2e_web_all_vis a
LEFT JOIN 
       sbg_published.web_funnel_detail_v4 b
       ON a.col1 = b.col1
```

I am running this query using `spark.sql()`
The first table has around `1 million` records and the second has `1.5 billion records`

I am trying to force spark to use broadcast join but instead, it is adopting sortmerge join.

Following are the spark params I have used

```
"spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold" = "4048576000"
"spark.sql.broadcastTimeout" = "100000"
"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" = 500
"spark.sql.adaptive.enabled" = "true"
"spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled" = "true"
"spark.sql.adaptive.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold" ="4048576000"
"spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin" = "false"
"spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries"="10"
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"="true"
"spark.shuffle.service.enabled"="true"
"spark.shuffle.compress"="true"
"spark.shuffle.spill.compress"="true"
"spark.driver.maxResultSize"="0"
```

This is the DAG - [image]

I also then tried this parameter -

> "spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin" = "false"

This made the sortmerge join to go and adopted shuffle hash join instead.

I am using spark 3.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68296266/5594180

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BROADCASTJOIN hint is not working in PySpark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622742/broadcastjoin-hint-is-not-working-in-pyspark-sql)

Comment: No - none worked so far! Still stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Besides "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold" , spark has hard broadcast size limit 8G.
You can't force spark to broadcast dataframe  once it exceeds 8G.
So you can try to resolve it by :

1. Rewrite the sql to broadcast the small table.
2. Rewrite the sql by union